# JOOQ: Database version is older than what dialect COCKROACHDB supports: 13.0.0

Tags: postgresql, jooq, cockroachdb

We use CockroachDB 22.2 and JOOQ 3.18.2.

In our logs, this message appears:

> Database version is older than what dialect COCKROACHDB supports: 13.0.0.
> Consider https://www.jooq.org/download/support-matrix to see what jOOQ version and edition supports which RDBMS versions.

The page shows that JOOQ supports CockroachDB since 20, since version 3.13.

What the message means then?

My theory is, that somehow, CockroachDB sometimes pretends to be PostgreSQL, and for the compatibility, it reports itself as PostgreSQL 13. But then, JOOQ mixes up the values, and reports COCKROACHDB and version 13, where it expects 22.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.18.4, there's a bug where this log message is reported erroneously: [#14944](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14944). You can safely ignore the message or mute it via your logger configuration until this bug is fixed.

Note that in the future, starting from jOOQ 3.19 and [#15050](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15050), this particular log message can be muted also via a generic system property:

```
-Dorg.jooq.log.org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.logVersionSupport=ERROR
```

[See also the section about logging system properties in the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-execution/logging-system-properties/)